# OAuth2, Azure, Asp.Net MVC5 Default template, cannot access db

Tags: asp.net, azure

In Asp.Net MVC5, I'm using the default template
I've set customer errors of in web.config. I'm trying to connect to google and facebook.  When I deploy to azure, i get the following... I've not done anything that I'm aware of locally to prepare the DB. Although I do have sql express installed for other reasons.

```
error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly when deploying to azure you need to specify a connection string for your project to connect to. In Azure you cant use the DefaultConnection string as it designed only to work locally

Comment: I did figure this out, forgot to come back and answer my own quesiton though.